# How to compute the Bessel function in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, bessel-functions

I want to compute the Bessel function of the first kind in MATLAB.

- J<sub>0</sub> = First kind zero order.
- J<sub>1</sub>: There is nothing mentioned what is J<sub>1</sub> in the article.
- But wikipidea says: The series indicates that −J<sub>1</sub>(x) is the
  derivative of J<sub>0</sub>(x).
- What is J<sub>1</sub> and how should I compute it in MATLAB?
- Should *r* be a constant value or variable?

Let us say I want to compute J<sub>0</sub>(*r*) and J<sub>1</sub>(*r*)

```
J0 = besselj(0,r);
J1 = -besselj(1,r);
```

Is the code for `J1` correct?

Comment: What you mean by implement? Do you want to code your own `bessel` function or just use MATLAB's built-in `besselj` [function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/besselj.html#mw_b63c9faa-8dee-4bd8-879a-92a756d6fe1e)? Did you checked the `besselj` documentation? It is clear in the examples what the first and second argument are.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/besselj.html), `besselj(α,r)` computes J<sub>α</sub>(*r*), the Bessel function of the first kind of order α. So if you want to compute the function for order 1, do

```
J1 = besselj(1,r);
```

Comment: Yes. I did the same. Thank you